# equal height vertical line in CSS

Tags: html, css

In the footer section, I have a 3 divs(with links) next to each other horizontally (float:left;).

Each div has different number of links. For example,

```
   Div1           Div2              Div3  
|  Contact    |   Feedback      |   Support Center
|  Delivery   |   Bonus Points  |   Order Notes
              |   Team          |   Newsletter
              |   Service
```

Here Div1 has 2 links only and the left vertical line is short. Div2 has 4 links and vertical line is big and div3 has 3 links and it is too short based on the links.

My CSS has this below,

```
#footer_verticalLineSeparator {
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
height: 100%;
}
```

But I need all vertical line need to be same equal height instead of adding image. And it need to be look like below.

```
   Div1           Div2              Div3  
|  Contact    |   Feedback      |   Support Center
|  Delivery   |   Bonus Points  |   Order Notes
|             |   Team          |   Newsletter
|             |   Service       |
|             |                 |
```

Is it possible in CSS to have equal vertical line? Need a solved link to show how it is possible.

Comment: simplest - make them all same fixed height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are fixed height, you have the method of Manish Mishra. If your columns must follow the height of its contents, you have the `table-cell` method.

http://jsfiddle.net/xFSe8/

```
.cont-2 {
    display:table;
}

.cont-2 .col {
    display:table-cell;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
}

<div class = "cont-2">
    <div class = "col col-1">
        <a>Apple</a>
        <a>Orange</a>
        <a>Peach</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "col col-2">
        <a>Pikachu</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "col col-3">
        <a>Apple</a>
        <a>Orange</a>
        <a>Peach</a>
        <a>Tomato</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all. Many of their solutions are correct. @TreeTree thank you so much.. I tried one by one.. it is working good from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not directely. But you can add a background containing the lines to the containing your columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a unique seperator elemnt with fixed height between the divs.

like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menuBox"></div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <div class="menuBox"></div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <div class="menuBox"></div>
    <div class="endFloats">
</div>
```

css:

```
.menuBox{display:inline-block;float:left;width:300px}
.seperator{display:inline-block;float:left; width:1px; border:1px solid #000}
.endFloats{display:block; height:1px; clear:both; line-height:1px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided your markup, I can only assume hence try this:

suppose your markup is like this:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footerSection">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#' >Contact </a></li>
            <li><a href='#' >Delivery </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footerSection">
       <ul>
            <li><a href='#' >FeedBack</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' >Bonus Points</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' >Team </a></li>
            <li><a href='#' >Service </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footerSection">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#' >Support Center </a><li>
            <li><a href='#' >Order Notes </a></li>
            <li><a href='#' >NewsLetter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both">
    </div>
</div>
```

make your css like this:

```
.footer{
    min-width:500px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.footerSection{
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
    min-height:140px;
    width:30%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
.footerSection:last-child{
    border:none;
}
.footerSection ul {
   list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7YQ9P/3)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like in the footer of StackOverflow? Isn't that possible with the new HTML5 elements?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CSS like this?

```
.footer {
    display: table;
    width: 540px;
    height: 150px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.pane {
    display: table-cell;
    border-left:1px dashed #000;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

HTML Sample

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="pane">
        <p>Contact</p>
        <p>Delivery</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <p>Feedback</p>
        <p>Bonus Points</p>
        <p>Team</p>
        <p>Service</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <p>Support Center</p>
        <p>Order Notes</p>
        <p>Newsletter</p>
    </div>
</div>
```